# DataFrame write information to specific column and row in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am quite new to Pandas and would like to find out how I can read and then write to a DataFrame row by from in a loop.

Input information

```
Index lemmatized_text MulNB
1     item inexpens   NaN
2     overall exper   NaN
3     screen n't co   NaN
4     screen not co   NaN
5     've view nume   NaN
```

Create the pandas DataFrame

```
df10 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['MulNB', 'lemmatized_text'])
```

Attempted code to loop through the information:

```
for i in range(1,len(df10)):
    test=df10['lemmatized_text'].loc[i]
    df10['MulNB'].loc[i]=model.predict(vec.transform(test))
    i+=1
```

Currently it iterates until line 10 and then it stops and shows the following:

[image]

Thank you for any assistance on this.

Comment: shouldn't `vec.transform(['test'])` be `vec.transform(test)`?

Comment: Valid point @enke, I however still am getting an error, please see error update in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the loop, you could use `apply`:

```
df10['MulNB'] = df10['lemmatized_text'].apply(lambda test: model.predict(vec.transform([test])))
```

but then again, it may be more efficient to use a list comprehension.

```
df10['MulNB'] = [model.predict(vec.transform([test])) for test in df10['lemmatized_text']]
```

I don't know how your model is set up but if it's a text mining model, I think it should be vectorized:

```
df10['MulNB'] = model.predict(vec.transform(df10['lemmatized_text']))
```

Answer (score 0):

To update/iterate over rows in Panadas Dataframe I would recommend you to checkout [iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) provided by Pandas.

```
for i, row in df10.iterrows():
    test = df10.loc[i,'lemmatized_text']
    df10.loc[i,'MulNB'] = model.predict(vec.transform(test))
```

Other Alternative is to use List Comprehension.

Comment: I do not think there is a way to use `=`  *equal* symbol inside list, instead use a method that replace this assignation, a example: `[df10.loc[i, 'MulNB'].assign(model.predict(vec.transform(df10.loc[i,'lemmatized_text']))) for i, row in df10.iterrows()]`, but obviously that this does not work... find out [on pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)